# IndexedDB cursor does not get next record after update on iOS

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have attempted to research similar cases, but nothing has matched what I am experiencing. Consider the following:

```
var req = indexedDB.open("myDatabase", 1);
req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
   var objStore = evt.target.result.createObjectStore("customers", { keyPath: "ID", autoIncrement: true });
   objStore.createIndex("fName", "fName", { unique: false });
   objStore.createIndex("lName", "lName", { unique: false });
   objStore.createIndex("country", "country", { unique: false });
   var obj1 = { fName: "James", lName: "Smith", age: 25, country: "United States", reviewStatus: "pending" };
   var obj2 = { fName: "Tim", lName: "Jones", age: 32, country: "Canada", reviewStatus: "pending"};
   var obj3 = { fName: "James", lName: "Miller", age: 22, country: "United States", reviewStatus: "pending"};
   var obj4 = { fName: "James", lName: "Thompson", age: 40, country: "United Kingdom", reviewStatus: "pending"};
   var obj5 = { fName: "Joseph", lName: "Harris", age: 28, country: "Canada", reviewStatus: "pending"};
   var obj6 = { fName: "James", lName: "Jackson", age: 30, country: "United States", reviewStatus: "pending"};
   objStore.add(obj1);
   objStore.add(obj2);
   objStore.add(obj3);
   objStore.add(obj4);
   objStore.add(obj5);
   objStore.add(obj6);
};
req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
   var tx = this.result.transaction("customers", "readwrite");
   var objStore = tx.objectStore("customers");
   var index = objStore.index("fName");
   var cnt = index.count(IDBKeyRange.only("James"));
   cnt.onsuccess = function () {
      console.log(cnt.result + " records with fName: James");
   };
   var cursor = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only("James"));
   cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
      var record = e.target.result;
      if (record) {
         var updateData = record.value;
         updateData.reviewStatus = "reviewed";
         //update some other fields

         var updateReq = record.update(updateData);
         console.log("updating record");
         record.continue();
      }
   };
   cursor.onerror = function () {
      console.log("error using cursor");
   };

   tx.oncomplete = function () {
     console.log("got to transaction oncomplete");
     //do other work required once cursor updates done
   };
   tx.onerror = function () {
      console.log("error in transaction");
   };
};
req.onerror = function () {
    console.log("error opening database");
};
```

My database has 4 records with fName = "James". I used Chrome (v71) to first test this and get the results:

> 4 records with fName: James
>  updating record
>  updating
>   record
>  updating record
>  updating record
>  got to
>   transaction oncomplete

Subsequent tests on Firefox (v64), Opera (v56), and Chrome for Android and all produced these expected results. When I test on iOS (11.4), I get the results:

> 4 records with fName: James
>  updating record
>  got to
>   transaction oncomplete

I don't get any console errors or any of the messages in my onerror functions. I cannot figure out why in iOS only the the first record is updated and the cursor doesn't move on to the other records. Is there an error in my code that I am unaware of or is this some kind of bug in iOS?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you share a complete and self-contained example of the problem, because then people can easily run it and observe the situation you describe.

Comment: Updated the example to include creating the object store, indexes, and a subset of data that would be found in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in Safari. I submitted a bug report here https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192987 - hopefully they will fix it in the near future!